# Why am I getting Google Drive notifications about strangers' documents?

Tags: notifications, malware, google-drive, push-notifications

Screenshot:

[image: Google Drive notification screenshot]

Is this just a new form of spam or phishing technique, basically betting that I'll click on the notification and look at the document? I haven't looked at any of them yet, but it seems utterly bizarre that Google Drive would notify me of the occurrence of anything in *someone else's document.*

A quick tour of the Russian alphabet and Google Translate reveals the document name as "Message No. FB-24".

[Cross-post](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=24763276)

Comment: Related on Google Drive Help, I guess: [Mentioned in comment in harmful/spam Google Doc by unknown person](https://support.google.com/drive/thread/66609110)

Comment: Thanks @AndrewT.; looks relevant! 325 upvotes and no response? Ouch.

Comment: Apparently the thread was locked, I'm not sure when and why...

Comment: [Dupe](https://support.google.com/drive/thread/6434357) with over 600 upvotes and no response! They're probably closing the discussions because people must be frothing at the mouth. Based on my interactions with GDrive support in the past i guess they are basically a money-making sweatshop by now, so I wouldn't expect a fix this side of the millennium.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me more then once and always on a chromebook. (I don't own one anymore) Anyway I just wanted to say something because it was malware in my case.